# 2 Constructors in Domain Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am in training and looking at some codes for web application. We using MVC in our organization, i'm not sure why we need 2 constructors like this, please explain it so i can have better idea about it. Thank you.

```
namespace ddc.Core.Domain
{
    public class Request : Entity
    {
        public Request()
        {

        }

        public Request(int buildingId, int adId, DateTime eventDate, DateTime eventStart, DateTime eventEnd, DateTime? timeOfApproval)
        {
            this.BuildingId = buildingId;
            this.AdId = adId;
            this.EventDate = eventDate;
            this.StartTime = eventStart;
            this.PowerNeed = powerNeed;
            this.EventDescription = eventDescription;
            this.EnteredBy = enteredBy;
            this.EnteredOn = enteredOn;
            this.TimeOfApproval = timeOfApproval;
        }

        public virtual int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public virtual int AdId { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? TimeOfApproval { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What methods? Are you referring to the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry i wasn't clear.

Comment: You don't *need* them, but they might come in handy if you want to instantiate a `Request` object and set its properties at the same time. Do you understand the general purpose of a constructor?

Comment: That looks like an EF class, if it is then the parameterless constructor is for EF to use.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor with lots of arguments allows someone to instantiate an object and set all the properties in one constructor call, which is often very handy:

```
var request = new Request(buildingId, adId, eventDate, eventStart, eventEnd, timeOfApproval);
```

But as soon as you define your own constructor, then there is no longer an auto-generated default constructor (which allows you to create the object without any arguments), so that had to be defined manually.

```
var request = new Request();

// Later...
request.BuildingId = buildingId;
request.AdId = adId;
request.EventDate = eventDate;
//...etc.
```

Hence there are two constructors to this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework then there must be a parameterless constructor. When Entity Framework maps from a database query to your Entities use the default constructor to instantiate a new instance of your Entity to fill it with the data retrieved from your database.

So, when you have the second one, that allows you to create an instance and set all properties

```
new Request(buildingId, adId, ...);
```

You need to add the first one (parameterless constructor) for EF. And it allows to create an instance and set only those properties that you need (or not set any of them) because all properties have public setter

```
new Request
{
    BuildingId =  buildingId,
    AdId =  adId,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter-less constructor should be because Entity Framework need it to create an object from Database. I recommend use an Internal scope for this. [More info here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors)